# PHP(Apache) doesn't execute BASH command (At + Wget)

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, at-job

So, guys, I have the following code:

```
<?php
  $url  = "http://example.com/filetorun.php";
  $time = date('g:i A d.m.Y', $res['sometime']); 
  echo `echo "wget --spider {$url}" | at -M {$time}`;
?>
```

The main idea is to wget some url at the specific time to perform some useful operations for me.

**What happens in the terminal?**

When I run this bash code. It works well giving me the output like this:

```
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 59 at Mon Jan 13 17:12:00 2020
```

**What happens in /var/log/apache2/error.log when I run my php script?**

It gets this output.

**What's about atq?**

I can see the job there only when I create it via the Terminal. When I create It from the php-script, I can not do that.

**What have I tried to do?**

I added users to /etc/at.allow and deleted them from /etc/at.deny

Comment: Why do you `echo` an `echo` which then outputs a `wget` command? Why aren't you using `exec()` (https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php) for this?

Comment: The webserver is not expected to execute scripts, you will run into more and more issues the deeper you go. Don't shell out at all (to wget, or to at) (in an insecure manner, no less): use e.g. cron and the php_curl library to make requests directly from PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: @thmspl: Note the pipe: this is supposed to send the command to `at`, not execute it directly. https://linux.die.net/man/1/at

Comment: @thmspl I tried to execute it via exec() too, it gave me the same result :c

Comment: As to "why not": `?url=http://evil.example.com/;rm%20-rf%20*` - guess what happens.

Comment: @Piskvorcc-by-sa3.0 I should execute some php script late on some day at some tie. There are no other ways as It seems to me

Comment: @Piskvorcc-by-sa3.0 No,you see it in the wrong way. My real url looks like example.com/page/keytocheck=wer67uhgfe456y

Comment: @Piskvorcc-by-sa3.0 I don't send any bash commands remotely

Comment: Are you on a shared hoster? Sometimes hoster are disabling some features for PHP scripts.

Comment: @thmspl No, I run it on the server of my company

Comment: @thmspl It seems to me there are some troubles with the privileges of apache user, when "at" runs under it at the specified time

Comment: But syslog is empty!

Comment: Is this question really about explaining that the PHP/Apache and your terminal account are distinct?

Comment: @mario No, It is about why I can't execute the bash command "at" in contrast of the executing it via the Terminal

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of detail to go on, but I direct your attention to this requirement of `at`:

> The value of the SHELL environment variable at the time of at invocation will determine which shell is used to execute the at job commands. If SHELL is unset when at is invoked, the user's login shell will be used; otherwise, if SHELL is set when at is invoked, it must contain the path of a shell interpreter executable that will be used to run the commands at the specified time.

Does your web server user have a login shell defined? `getent passwd` or `grep /etc/passwd` to determine. Regardless, I suggest setting the shell to use in the command itself, to prevent issues where someone chnahes the default shell of the invoking user.

If this is not the issue, we probably need more detail.